# Database Migration Trait laravel 5 package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So i want to `use DatabaseMigrations;` in Laravel 5.4 package Unit test, I've my package migrations in **migrations folder** so when i tried my Unit tests the `use DatabaseMigrations;` use the project migrations not the package migrations, so please if someone has any idea how to configure the `use DatabaseMigrations;` to use my package migrations i'll be very appreciative.

Comment: and the reason you tagged it with laravel-4 is for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use trait like `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;` :

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

You can get more idea from [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing)